# pick random number out of a list

Tags: java, android

I have a list of 3 variables: (`a`,`b`,`c`). Is there a way to pick randomly out of this list if some condition are made? let's say:

```
if(some variable=2)
{
    pick one variable from the list
}
if(some variable=4)
{
    pick 2 variables from the list
}
..
and here comes the tricky part

if(some variable=10)   
{
    pick 5 variables out of the list( here the variables can duplicate)

    it can be something like this : a,a,a,b,b
}
```

I'm using Java for Android.

Comment: What's the problem; why can't you get it done? Should you be using `==` instead???

Comment: this is just my idea..i can't seem to get this done in android..i know I have to use ==

Comment: did the answers below helped you ?

Comment: i'm working on it now...i will come back with an updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a method that generates a random number and uses it to get an element from the list. Invoke it from inside each `if` statement and that should do the trick. Something like (and this is just an idea):

```
private Object random() {
    Random random = new Random();
    int index = random.nextInt(3);
    return yourList.get(index);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using array or arrayList, you'll need to use the Random object.

```
ArrayList<String> yourArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
yourArrayList.add("a");
yourArrayList.add("b");
yourArrayList.add("c");
Random randomGenerator = new Random();
int index = randomGenerator.nextInt(yourArrayList.size());
String item = yourArrayList.get(index);
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help you. This code is for java. If you are on android, just ignore Scanner and pass a variable as you want. I used Scanner just to take input from console.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Select{
    Random r = new Random();
    public Select(int num){
        int a;
        char [] list = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
        a=num/2;
        char [] show = new char [a];
        int [] rand = new int [a];
        for(int i=0;i<a;i++){
            rand[i]=r.nextInt(3);
        }
        for(int i=0;i<a;i++){
            show[i]=list[rand[i]];
        }
        for(int i=0;i<a;i++){
            System.out.println(show[i]);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a no.");
        int no = scan.nextInt();
        Select s = new Select(no);

    }
}
```